# Vuejs facebook send to messenger plugin re-renders everytime a new I item is added in list

Tags: vue.js, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am creating a page with the list of products , I have added send to messenger plugin next to each of the products.

I have tried initializing FB in the parent component and creating the send to messenger in child component , but its not rendering those buttons, neither if I add FB.init in my index.html file.

So I added FB.init in the child component and it created the button , but every time a new product is added all the buttons re-renders, that results in flicker of the button. Here is my child and  parent component

parent

```
<template>
<div>
<ProductCard :products="products" />
<infinite-loading @infinite="infiniteHandler" ref="infiniteLoading">
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            products:[]
        }
        },
    methods:{
            infiniteHandler($state){
                axios.get('/getproduct').then((response) => {
                    response.data.data.forEach(element => {
                        this.products.push(element);

                    });
                });
            }

        }
    }
</script>
```

child

```
<template>
<div>
    <div v-for="product in products">
            <span class=""> {{product.name}}</span>
            //show fb send to messenger
            <div class="fb-send-to-messenger" 
            messenger_app_id="123456XXXXX" 
            page_id="147895XXXX" 
            :data-ref="'Learn_More_'+product.id" 
            color="blue" 
            size="large"
            >
    </div>


</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props:['products]
    data(){
        return{

        }
        },
    mounted(){
            this.init();   
        },
    methods:{
            if (window.FB) {

                    window.FB.init({
                        appId      : '123456XXXXX',
                        status     : true,
                        xfbml      : true,
                        version    : 'v3.3'
                    });

                     var finished_rendering = function() {
                       console.log("finished rendering");    
                    }
                    window.FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.render', finished_rendering);
                }

        }
    }
</script>
```